# Quando clicar, quero definir a frase através dos índices

Tags: java, android, array, string

Como podem ver no código, quando clico eu estou definindo a frase de forma randômica, porém quando eu clicar, eu quero que venha a frase que eu mesmo definir através dos índices, como faço isso?

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textoNovaFrase;
    private Button botaoNovaFrase;

    private String[] frases = {
            "Se você traçar metas absurdamente altas e falhar, seu fracasso será muito melhor que o sucesso de todos",
            "O sucesso normalmente vem para quem está ocupado demais para procurar por ele",
            "Se você não está disposto a arriscar, esteja disposto a uma vida comum"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textoNovaFrase = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoNovaFraseId);
        botaoNovaFrase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoNovaFraseId);

        botaoNovaFrase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Random randomico = new Random();
                int numeroAleatorio = randomico.nextInt( frases.length );

                textoNovaFrase.setText( frases[ numeroAleatorio ] );
            }
        });
```

Comment: A pergunta ficou confusa para mim, pode explicar melhor o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Quando eu clicar no botaonovafrase, vai gerar uma frase, mas agora eu não quero que seja de forma randômica, quero saber qual frase vai vim, tenho três frases aí, quero botar as três em ordem, quando eu clicar no botanovafrase, vai gerar a primeira frase, quando eu clicar novamente, vai gerar a segunda frase, e ao clicar mais uma vez, vai gerar a terceira frase, como fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Se pretende ir colocando frases diferentes de forma sequencial pode utilizar um campo na classe para saber em que posição vai e ir incrementando à medida que mostra:

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ....
    private String[] frases = {
            "Se você traçar metas absurdamente altas e falhar, seu fracasso será muito melhor que o sucesso de todos",
            "O sucesso normalmente vem para quem está ocupado demais para procurar por ele",
            "Se você não está disposto a arriscar, esteja disposto a uma vida comum"
    };
    private int posicao = 0; //novo campo aqui

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        botaoNovaFrase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                textoNovaFrase.setText( frases[ posicao++] ); //mostra e incrementa aqui

            }
        });
```

Note que isto gera um problema se clicar demasiadas vezes pois passa a dimensão do array `frases`. Pode melhorar e corrigir esse problema fazendo:

```
textoNovaFrase.setText( frases[posicao%frases.length] );
posicao++;
```

Assim gera-lhe sempre um índice entre 0 a e o tamanho do array, que irá funcionar corretamente sempre.

Alerto ainda que com para ficar com a solução 100% correta terá que guardar e restaurar este novo campo no estado da Activity, particularmente em `onSaveInstanceState` e em `onRestoreInstanceState`, caso contrário rodando a orientação do dispositivo ou outro tipo de alterações de configuração fazem-lhe perder a posição em que ia.

[Leia mais sobre o estado de uma Activity aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado! me ajudou bastante, só mais duas perguntinhas, rs.  É possível eu criar condições, tipo abro o indice 2, se

Comment: É possível eu salvar os dados quando clicar, tipo eu cliquei uma vez foi para o índice = 1, quando fechar a aplicação e abrir novamente, vai está no indice = 1 e quando clicar vai para o indice = 2.

Comment: @L.jack De nada. Sim claro que é possível guardar. Pode fazer isso tanto através de [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) que é mais usado até para configurações. Assim como também pode fazer com [SqLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) que é mais usado a nível de dados de usuário normais.